# store html tag after extract html with imacro

Tags: imacros

Is is possible to have the full html tag with imacro ? When I don't use "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" option to check the value of the extract, I can see the html tag (ie : < br >) in the popup window.

When I want to store the extract in a variable, all the html tags disappear.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem tag is `<br>` (as the new line character for 'iMacros' strings). So try to replace it, for example, as follows:

```
SET someVar EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/<br>/g, '<br >');")
```

In general the solution depends on what you are going to do with this variable.